# How can I hook into creating a new post and execute wp_die(), before the post is inserted into the database?

Tags: posts, hooks, actions

Info about wp_die from codex: Kill WordPress execution and display HTML message with error message. A call to this function complements the die() PHP function. The difference is that HTML will be displayed to the user. It is recommended to use this function only when the execution should not continue any further.

I have code:

```
function myHook( $post_ID, $post )
{
     wp_die('Error', 'Error',  array( 'response' => 500, 'back_link' => true ));
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'myHook', 0, 2 );
```

Problem is that error page appears, but post is still inserted. Shouldn't saving be interrupted by this hook? If I misunderstood description, how can I break execution so post will not be saved?

EDIT: I just found that save_post is called after instert to database not before. Does there exist any function called before insert that i can hook into?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try filtering with `wp_insert_post_data` instead. It's from `wp-includes/post.php`, line 2864.

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'post_publish_filter_wpse_82356' );
function post_publish_filter_wpse_82356( $data ) {
    // view/manipulate $data
    if ('publish' == $data['post_status']) {
        $msg = '<pre>' . var_export($data, true) . '</pre>';
        wp_die($msg);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

`publish` is the `post_status` when you click the *Publish* or *Update* button. The four statuses I've found are:

- **auto-draft** - self-explanatory (also, status is set to this when you click *Add New*)
- **draft** - when you click *Save Draft* button
- **inherit** - when you click *Preview* button
- **publish** - when you click *Publish* or *Update* button

Comment: According to codex it works only for updates. It's not called on inserts.

Comment: @user1666774: See my updated Answer.

Comment: Problem is that in this filter i don't have access to data from add_meta_box

Comment: See my updated (again - I've finally tested enough, hopefully no more edits :) ) answer for the statuses I've found and updated example code. Regarding add_meta_box data, that'll have to be another Question.

Comment: It's possible you can find the `add_meta_box` data in one of WP's global variables or pull it from a function call.

Comment: If you look at the request header you might even find the metadata in `$_POST`